# Which version of MSDN subscription / cheapest source

Tags: msdn

I've searched here for the various MSDN subscription questions, but the answers I've found are either Empower or MVP focused, or out of date with their answer links.

I'm mostly a Delphi developer (solo), with no current need for Visual Studio. I need all Windows OS versions for testing, and ditto for Office, for some integration requirements a few of my apps have and version support the very occasional Access project. I don't need betas, sales support, or the like, and I'm not inclined to get back into MS hoop-jumping (I used to have a company that was an MSCP, way back when -- gadz they made me tired! ). I've also had a company a few years ago that had an Empower subscription (which was great, but no longer really applicable to my current situation).

I'm thinking the MSDN Premium is the only one which covers my need for Office. Is that correct, and if so, what's the best (i.e. cheapest) source to acquire it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for recommendations on subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Technet.  About $350USD online for the download only edition.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/default.aspx

Comment: Perfect - thanks! Didn't realize TechNet came w/Office, etc. Really appreciate that you posted this -- exactly what I was looking for. : )

Comment: P.S. Nice coupon codes here: http://www.retailmenot.com/view/technet.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1):

If the version (by this I mean, Standard or Professional, etc) of Office isn't a determining factor, then check out the [Expression Professional Subscription](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EPS_Overview.aspx). This package comes with a copy of Office Standard edition as well as copies of Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7.

You'll have to double-check the licensing, but it is a lot cheaper than MSDN Premium (at least for us in the UK).

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the [Microsoft BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) program is suitable for your needs.